# What is "Remind Me" supposed to do?

Tags: ios, mail.app, notifications

When I use the Remind Me feature in iOS Mail (iOS 16, iPhone 8) I imagine that when the fire date has passed I'll receive a local notification reminding me about the message. That never happens. I'm also never alerted in the app. I can set the remind date to one minute in the future and watch the minutes pass without any results.

While the feature is already useless to me as it is, before concluding it's defective I thought I'd ask what's *supposed* to happen. In what way is it meant to "remind me"?

*All relevant notification permissions are enabled for the app and feature in question.*

Comment: It's supposed to move it to the top of your inbox and send a notification

Comment: @Ezekiel Are you sure? If so, write an answer and I'll accept it. But what about those not currently in the inbox, like archived and sent items? They won't appear in the inbox, will they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, Remind Me will send a notification and move the message to the top of the mailbox it resides in.

Ex: If you mark "Remind Me" on an email in your Archive folder, it will go to the top of the Archive folder when the time comes.

You can check your notification settings. Go to Settings > Notifications > Mail. Check that notifications are enabled, then tap Customize Notifications > Remind Me to check those are also enabled.